# display custom error message in Azure powershell and exit

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to get the list of storages name for a specific subscription using powershell. If I have the correct subscription name, I get the result but if there is some mistype then I get this error:

> Select-AzSubscription : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.
> Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $subName
> CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzContext], ArgumentException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMContextCommand

What would be the best option to handle the error message and exit out from the script with a message "Couldn't find the subscription".
Here is the powershell code:

```
###Set a subscription name
$subName = "Test SubscriptionName"

Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $subName

### Select storage accounts based for above subscription
$sAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount | select StorageAccountName
$sAccount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution should be use the scripts below:

```
$subName = "Test SubscriptionName"

try{ 
     Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $subName -ErrorAction Stop        
    } 
catch [System.ArgumentException]{
        Write-Host "Couldn't find the subscription"

        #use exit to exit the script
        exit
     }

#Select storage accounts based for above subscription      
$sAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount | select StorageAccountName
$sAccount
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense! That way, I can see where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it using try-catch method. Here is the solution:

```
 $subName = "Test SubscriptionName"

Try { 
     Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $subName -ErrorAction Stop
        #Select storage accounts based for above subscription
         $sAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount | select StorageAccountName
          $sAccount
         } 
Catch{
        Write-Host  $_.Exception.Message
     }
```

Comment: It's not a good solution. If the subname is correct, and the error is from the following code like `Get-AzStorageAccount`, your code still prints the message "couldn't find the subscription".

Comment: @IvanYang how about now? is it possible to add a custom error message with the Exception message ? For example: if the error is in subName then 'Please re-enter your subName' + Exception message and if it is in Get-AzStorageAccount then 'You don't have storage account' + Exception?

Comment: yes, you can add a custom error message. And you can also specify the exception type as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @IvanYang, just saw your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a null test:

```
$sub = Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $subName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($sub -eq $null) 
  { 
    "Couldn't find the subscription"
    ## Add you exit code here!
  }  
else
  { "Good subname" }
```